# How can I log out from Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, faq, logout

I can't log out. This was a test account, and now I can't log in to my normal account.

I've tried to remove all the cookies. From [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29), when I'm refreshing, I get logged out, but then I'm logged in again. What files on disk should I remove to be logged out permanently or is there a menu option I missed?

Anyway, how does Stack Overflow do this?

---

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Answer (score 235):

You can log out of Stack Overflow via the drop-down under the *Stack Exchange logo menu* to the right:

[image: Stack Overflow log out link]

This applies *just* to the site your are active on. You really want to log out from the *OpenID* provider, too, as anyone can now use your computer to log back in to Stack Overflow, often without being challenged to re-enter credentials. How you do that depends on what provider you are using.

For Google, Yahoo, Facebook, etc. you'll have to visit their sites and find the log-out option there.

You can find what OpenID providers are authorised by clicking on the *my logins* link under the *Edit Profile & Settings* tab in your profile:

[image: my logins overview]

Answer (score 43):

The simplest way is to go to http://stackoverflow.com/users/logout. Also works on other StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 8):

Viewing from the browser on mobile, I struggled with this for way too long...

[Martijn's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254109/how-can-i-log-out-from-stack-overflow/262160#262160) is correct, but for mobile users you'll probably need to scroll the last few icons to find the button Martijn mentioned.

Stack Overflow UX designers - it's annoying to not know how to log out of your site. It's even more **annoying to have to go to another site to log out of this one** (as Martijn explained).

### Update

The *OpenID* link Martijn shared didn't have a "log out" option when I visited, so I'm not sure if that is still a valid part of the process or not.

Comment: Well, I guess [the Products menu is much more important](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnEuP.jpg) than the main Stack Exchange menu containing the "log out" link ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Related: *[Support for OpenID ended on July 25, 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/)*. Some updates may be in order.

Comment: On mobile the logout dropdown menu is present for Stack Exchange sites but not for Stack Overflow, it simply disappears.