# why is Logout button really hard to locate?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

My stackoverflow account is always logged in on my computer, when i tried to logged it out because my friend needs to login his, we were trying to find the logout button and it was once on the profile page now it is not. We didn't find it so we just cleared cache, until now im kinda lost, where it is.

Comment: and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254109/how-to-logout-from-stack-overflow

Comment: It's in the "Stack Exchange" drop-down in the top left corner.