# All I see is "Join the Community" – how do I login from Chrome?

Tags: support, login, google-chrome

When I use Firefox, there is a "login" link at the right-hand side of the navbar. In Chrome, this only says "Join the community".

I've searched and searched for some way to login from Chrome, but found nothing. How can I log in to this website from Chrome like I do from Firefox?

Comment: "Join the community" means "sign up and link the created account to my existing Stack Exchange account".

Comment: Well, this is a poorly asked question, but it is not at all "unclear". In Firefox, he sees a "login" link at the top of the page. In Chrome, all he sees is a "Join the community" link. Not sure how to make it substantially more clear than that... Voted to reopen. (Of course, dorukayhan already has posted the answer as a comment.)

Answer (score 6):

When I go to SO using Chrome in incognito mode I see the "sign up" and "login" links as expected.

[image]

The only time you see "join this community" is when you are currently signed into a Stack Exchange and you do not yet have an account with the specific community you are visiting.  This is what I see when I go to Academics.SE when signed in since I don't have an account there:

[image]

The login to Stack Exchange is browser specific and is generally persistent unless you explicitly sign out.  So the most likely explanation for your experience is you (or someone else using the same computer & browser) previously signed into a SE account that does not have a Stack Overflow account associated with it, and then never signed out.

So you should try logging out of that account from Chrome (see instructions in [How to logout from Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254109/how-to-logout-from-stack-overflow)) and then try to sign in with the account you want to use.