# How to logout from new Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, logout

How do I logout? The StackExchange link is gone from the top.

Maybe it is obvious for somebody, but I've been to almost any tab I could think of and all over my profile. Help, let me out!

Comment: You can't! You belong to us now!

But seriously: hamburger menu (upper right) -> logout

Comment: Wow, that's where I always wanted it to be! Just got confused by the hamburger shape and the pop up... Thanks, you saved my day!

Comment: @Martijn, not defending the quality or the necessity of the question at all, but I'm not 100% sure it's actually a duplicate: this relates to the "new" navigation bar, and I don't think the linked duplicate has an answer for this.

Comment: @yivi: we just need to update the screenshots. The hamburger menu is exactly the same menu, only the location and look changed.

Comment: There is probably **yet another** duplicate that applies though... :P

Comment: @MartijnPieters I looked for the answers before and found several years worth of questions and duplicates, but no answer about the new design. I think such questions should just always be kept up to date.

Comment: @Noidea: that's easier said than done. I have way too many answers to keep track of which ones might need updating when the UI changes.

Comment: In order to reduce the cost of keeping up to date screenshots, We should eliminate every one that try to logout or refuse to merge into the community spirit. The Be Nice Swat Force need something to realse the pressure.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262160/1995714