# How do I log out of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

This isn't my account. I looked everywhere a traditional website would put the log out button. The profile. The Stack Overflow icon. I checked the help. This is a little meta. It can not be avoided.

Comment: Top right of window is a list of all SE sites. Top right there is log out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LOL. I don't think I will get this marked as an answer since you will log out.

[image: Here]

Comment: Wow, that's tiny.  I found it.  Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. It confused me for while too.

Comment: Yes, but [there is one more step to do to *really* log out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254109/how-can-i-log-out-from-stack-overflow/262160#262160) (password actually required to log back in).

Answer (score 1):

Top right corner, click on the msg icon (follow this image)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 icons on the top of the website.

Click the last one which looks like[image]

The drop-down menu is having the log out button.