# How do I force a login to Stack Overflow in Chrome?

Tags: support, login

I can login to Stack Overflow via MS [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge), but not Chrome. I was in Chrome yesterday and it prompted me to log in and I incorrectly chose *Login via Google*. I want to log in with my user name and password.

Whenever I try to login via Chrome now it gives me the "Confirm your new account" screen. I don't want a new account; I want to log in to my existing one using my email address and password.

Comment: You should be able to [log out from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254109/215552), and then you'll be able to log in with the correct credentials.

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout and take it from there

Comment: The way this works is dumb. I used my google account to sign up for another stack exchange site. And then I was logged out of stack overflow, and could only sign up for stack overflow with google. There was no option to login with email and pass. I had to use the logout link posted by @rene.