# How do you switch between your several accounts when you're already logged in?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, accounts

I am using two accounts daily: one private account which I mostly use to access Stack Overflow, and a company account which I use to access my Stack Overflow Team.

I am usually logged in with my private account in my default browser. But when I receive a notification from my Team and click the link to access it, I obviously receive an error:
[image: Image describing the error]

My workaround is usually to copy the link from the email to a private browsing session, but this is far from being ideal...

So my question is: how do you easily switch accounts? (eg: Google or Microsoft usually allow you to click your profile picture or user name to switch accounts. Other sites at least offer a sign out button. What's your solution?)

**EDIT**:
Yes! I could use 2 computers, 2 OS session or 2 browser sessions... But this is far from being ideal! I use the account I created myself mainly for work too... Whenever I have work related questions, my hard earned reputation is very handy (even if not that big). So really, I need to use the two accounts daily during my work time. I suspect it will be the same for most "Team" users (for which their "Team" account is managed by their company).
I was a big advocate of StackOverflow for Teams in my company, but this is becoming a hindrance, really (most of my workmates are in the same situation). I would think twice again if I had to recommend it to someone, just because of this usability issue.

Comment: use two different browsers perhaps?

Comment: yeah, not ideal... especially when links opens from  / to your default browser usually...

Comment: [Use a good browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/)

Comment: Or log out and log in again. Do you not know how to log out?

Comment: And SO has a signout button: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254109/how-can-i-log-out-from-stack-overflow

Comment: I had indeed never seen the log out button on stack overflow! Now that would be great if there was such a link (to log out or to switch account) on the error page (cause this page doesn't have the top bar...). I will also try to play with extensions. Thanks @Zoe

Comment: Just for the record: SO doesn't support multiple accounts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login

Comment: How about switching users in the OS? That would also help keep work and not-work separate.

Comment: Sure, I could also switch computers... I have added some background to the question to explain why none of the workarounds are really satisfying.

Comment: I think it would be nice to have a "master" account and be able to attach accounts to that. Making the master and links between accounts private. It could also serve to secure unintentional double voting.

Comment: I use [SessionBox](https://sessionbox.io/). No affiliation whatsoever. I use it to log in as 4 different test users for my company product. I noticed it can get wonky with some sites like soundcloud, i.e. I can't seem to save multiple logins for long.