# Where is the Stack Overflow logout button located?

Tags: discussion

I was trying to log out from the Stack Overflow platform, but I can't find the signout button.

I have used [ChatGPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChatGPT), but I still can't see the signout button.

> To sign out of your Stack Overflow account, you can follow these steps:
>
> 1. Go to the Stack Overflow website at [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com) and make sure you are signed in.
> 2. Click on your profile picture in the top right corner of the screen to open the dropdown menu.
> 3. Click on "Log Out" at the bottom of the dropdown menu.
> 4. You will be asked to confirm that you want to log out. Click "Log Out" again to confirm.
> 5. You should now be signed out of your Stack Overflow account.
>
> Note that if you are signed in with a Google, Facebook, or Microsoft account, you will need to sign out of that account separately.

Comment: *I have used chatgpt but I still can't see the signout button.* ... Just another example ChatGPT is useless.

Comment: @rene It's great at generating works of fiction though

Comment: My favorite
[answer on how to log out from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364325).
Maybe you shouldn't ask ChatGPT?

Comment: It amuses me more that people refer to ChatGPT for *wrong* answers before they even consider searching the problem on their favourite search engine. Putting the title of this question into Google plenty answers with the *correct* answer.

Comment: It's impressive to me how often this question is re-asked. The interface is really bad, IMO.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Welcome to Hotel California, you can never leave.

Answer (score 17):

Press this icon here, then press log out.

[image]