How to get back to a Chat
A question OP invited me to Chat. I joined the chat on one system, and posted some replies.
But now, on another system, I can't see any menu, icon or option that lets me rejoin that chat.
What did I miss?

Goto https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/17523866?tab=recent

You can reach chat from the menu at the top right, in the drop down it has links to logout, chat and help

Chat doesn't get the love it needs, for example easy discovery in the UI. Instead we've got Discussions and AI. We can't have it all .... :(

There are two things users can't find on this site: Logout  and Chat. Those are tucked away in a little hiding place, so much that we had to create a specific [tag:faq] for user guidance: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254109/how-can-i-log-out-from-stack-overflow

For your tag problems, please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/259919#259919

To see all rooms you're currently in, go to the "mine" tab on chat.stackoverflow.com (or the same page on chat.stackexchange.com, in case the chat was there).
If you're not currently in the room (there's a timeout), click your display name in the top bar, then click the "recent" tab.  This will show you all your recent messages, and you'll be able to see the room there, as long as you've sent at least one message to it.
If you haven't sent at least one message, but the chat was created from a comment discussion with you, you can go to the all rooms page and search for your display name, as that's included in the name of rooms created this way.
